# Is this mold in hot sauce?

Tags: canning

I have several 1 year old bottles of fermented Serrano hot sauce (I do not remember if this batch had an onion in it or not).

The sauce was canned via hot fill hold processing in woozy bottles at a safe temperature and time held at that temperature according to University of Wisconsin food safety charts. pH at canning time was 3.29 (according to a calibrated electronic meter).

Note: I am not interested in a discussion about hot-fill-hold versus water bath canning. I realize that home canning authorities don’t “allow” this process, but it is the standard FDA certified process for commercial canning, and it is the only option for hot sauce in woozy bottles (plastic caps can’t be water bath canned).

All of the bottles have settled solids and a clear liquid layer on top — that’s expected as the sauce isn’t filtered. But some of the bottles have a layer between the liquid and settled solids of something that I assume is a fungi of some sort, but I’d like to know what it likely is as it doesn’t look like a traditional mold. In fact it really can’t be a traditional mold (which are all aerobic) as the bottles still have a vacuum seal (opened one to confirm) and the layer is submerged anyway so could get oxygen even from the small concentration that remains in the headspace in all canning.

The sauce remains at a pH below 3.4.

[image: Bottle without the layer]
[image: Bottle with the layer]

Comment: Welcome to SA!  The layer honestly looks like mother-of-vinegar.  Is there any way it could be?  Maybe share the recipe?

Comment: There’s no vinegar in it — it’s just a mash of serranos with 3% salt added and fermented. In some batches I’ve added a small amount of onion also.

Comment: Hmm, but now that you’ve got me thinking, that’d be an interesting idea. Acetobachter is common in the environment, but I’d have expected hot fill hold processing to kill all of that (boiling when added to the jar; above 150° in the jar for 5+ minutes, and above 190° for the initial seconds, either of which is effectively sterilizing for bacteria).

Comment: Could be an oxidative layer - sediment below is non-oxidized, while that at the liquid interface is?

Comment: @bob1 That certainly could be part of it, but that layer moves around cohesively (it will fall apart easily if you shake it, but if you move the bottle around more gently it acts like it’s a single thing).